# CubeGeometry VS BoxGeometry in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am learning Three.js. I can't find a proper answer about the difference between CubeGeometry vs BoxGeometry. I am getting the same output for both. Please help.

**CubeGeometry:**

```js
var geomatry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0XF3FFE2});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomatry,material);
mesh.position.set(0,0,-1000);
scene.add(mesh);
```

**BoxGeometry:**

```js
var geomatry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0XF3FFE2});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomatry,material);
mesh.position.set(0,0,-1000);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CubeGeometry` is just an alias for `BoxGeometry`. Keep in mind that `CubeGeometry` is actually deprecated.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4888a99ca0161f2b5fea0e9ae9ce845891c50999/src/Three.Legacy.js#L80

Comment: I have just checked the deprecated list from the documentation. Yes you are correct CubeGeometry is deprecated. we can view the deprecated list from here https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/deprecated/DeprecatedList